# How can I efficiently navigate a Git repo to follow project development?

Tags: git, revision-history

I am trying to understand a relatively new but non-trivial tool being developed in a git repository.

There is not much documentation in the code but the repository has picked up <100 commits so far, and I can see myself understanding what is going on better if I do something like:

1. `checkout` the very first commit; look at some code
2. `checkout` say ~5-6 commits later; look at how it changed
3. rinse-and-repeat #2 till I'm up-to-date

.. instead of just looking at *all* the code at the HEAD of master right now, which is a lot more complex.

The problem with my idea is that once I `git checkout $commit_1`, I get into a detached head state, so to go "up" to any newer commit I have to `git checkout master` *again*, and then work my way down to the commit I want. Is there a more convenient way to do this? i.e. check out an old commit, and then ask git to show me newer commits and move to one of them.

Comment: `git checkout master~82` ... `git checkout master~77` etc.

Comment: @Zeeker that is quite concise and convenient!

Comment: The [Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) chapter of the progit book might interest you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to check out `master` again all the time, or scribble down loads of SHA-1's on a piece of paper. At any stage, you can run

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph master
```

For convenience, you may want to define the following alias, as many Git users do:

```
git config alias.lg "log --oneline --decorate --graph"
```

Then the command above simply becomes

```
git lg master
```

This will output the log of the entire ancestry (albeit in a concise form) of your `master` branch, no matter "where you are" in the commit graph.

It's a nice way to get your bearings and identify which commit you want to check out or inspect next, via its corresponding short SHA-1 hash. Note that using the `--decorate` flag shows you where you are (`HEAD`).

### Example

Here is an example of me navigating one of my own Git repositories:

```sh
$ git branch
* master
$ git tag
v0.1
v0.2
v0.3
$ git checkout v0.3
Note: checking out 'v0.3'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at cfc71e4... mention compatibility with subset of Octave syntax
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph master
* 73ec762 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) improve brace style
* ffc8d67 remove superfluous word; delete trailing whitespace
* 3f8b8db remove obsolete comment about mcode
* f9f9fd0 remove .DS_Store file that was accidentally added
* cc855ab clarify description of mlonlyheader option
* 7553ccf change contact email
* 4d860e9 correct remarks on shell-escape and backtick
* 9a2ef02 corrected typo in Tips & tricks
* f0badb5 minor improvements in documentation
* cfc71e4 (HEAD, tag: v0.3) mention compatibility with subset of Octave syntax
* 7db2c88 Preventive bugfix: replace \toks@ by \toks@mlpr
* 01fdc43 delete OS-specific files from .gitignore
...
```

Comment: Very cool! This is the most convenient way that I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

Decide from the `git log` which commits are of interest.  Make a note of their SHA's and then just check them out.  No need to stop by master each time.

Example:

```
$ git checkout 315e25
Note: checking out '315e25'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 315e25a... 85192566 - Use Linker js namespace for verifying link
07:35:55 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropnot/_/rails_apps/linker (detached from 315e25a)
$ git checkout d93b9c
Previous HEAD position was 315e25a... 85192566 - Use Linker js namespace for verifying link
HEAD is now at d93b9c7... 85192548 - Use Linker js domain for show group members
07:36:13 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropnot/_/rails_apps/linker (detached from d93b9c7)
$
```

When you are done checking out the commit history and various commits of interest you can return to master:

```
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was d93b9c7... 85192548 - Use Linker js domain for show group members
Switched to branch 'master'
07:37:37 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropnot/_/rails_apps/linker master
$ g
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

You can also use the relative numbering to step through SHA's as detailed in Zeeker's comment.